# How To Copy Files From Local Windows Machine To Remote Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I want to copy a file from my local machine to a remote server. My local machine is running on Windows 10 and I use PuTTY to connect to the remote server, which is running Ubuntu.

Comment: If you look at [asking](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you'll notice that your question is of topic.

Comment: You can use WinSCP to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You must use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) to connect to the remote Ubuntu server, not PuTTY.

PuTTY allows you to connect to a shell prompt, WinSCP allows you to transfer files, so it's the latter that you must use. Both programs use SSH to connect to a remote server, so you must just make sure that the SSH daemon (`ssh`) is running on your remote Ubuntu machine and is accepting connections.